# minimize two loss functions in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I want to minimize two loss functions the mean squared error and the KL Divergence.
It is possible to implement this on Keras
something like

```
loss =tf.keras.losses.KLDivergence() + tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
model.compile(optimizer="Adam",
              loss=loss 
              )
```

This code gives me error, as I can't sum those functions

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom loss like this -

```
import tensorflow.keras as K

def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    l = K.backend.sum(K.losses.KLDivergence(y_true, y_pred), K.losses.MeanSquaredError(y_true, y_pred))
    return l

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=custom_loss,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The reason you can sum those 2 is that you are trying to sum up the objects of the 2 classes. Instead, you need to call them and sum up their results.

Comment: The solution works perfectly . But when I minimize it (the two combined loss functions) ,The loss goes under 0 ,which diverge it from the minimal value of the MSE ,as well as and the KL Divergence   which normally is always non-negative . Why does the loss goes under 0 ?

Comment: That is completely specific to the data and the model you are building. I can't comment on why the loss is negative since the method above doesn't cause that in any form (its a sum between 2 losses, that's it!). Also, KL Divergence is positive over the total dataset as it is a sum itself, but not always. Check - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43849/how-to-ensure-the-non-negativity-of-kullback-leibler-divergence-kld-metric-rela

Comment: Do mark this problem solved if you are able to build a custom loss function, as that was the original question. I can try helping the other question if you post it separately since these are 2 different issues.